# Trunc mail address in js

Tags: javascript, email

I need to remove what is after the `@` in an email address in a javascript var like that:
`exemple@mail.com` to `exemple` for example, how I can make that because I have seen the function

`Math.trunc()`

But to replace the `user.DisplayName` by the truncated email with in my code :

```
var user = user.DisplayName;
var email = user.email;
 if (user === null ) {
   //truncate email (user.email) 
   $(user).text(displayName);
  }
 else {
   //...
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `indexOf` to get the index of "@", and `slice` to cut the part before `"@"`:

```js
function trunc(email) {
  return email.slice(0, email.indexOf("@"));
}

console.log(trunc("example@mail.com"));
```